# how to install background location update service Cordova + angular js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, background, socket.io

I am using cordova along with angularjs, i want to update location of user every 15 min kind. Is there any best way of achieving it. Is it feasible to user socket.io along with background service.
I want my service to run completely background irrespective of my app is running in foreground or not.

Comment: You have to write your own code for this task. The problem is, that Apple will not allow this background process and Android will kill your process if the memory of the device is going low.

Comment: @Joerg Then how can i get mobile location every 15 min. You mean to say its impossible??